# Why with so many US job vacancy today, the foreign policy still make it nearly impossible to work in US as a foreigner?

Tags: united-states, visa

Why with so many US job vacancy today, the foreign policy still make it nearly impossible to work in US as a foreigner? I mean for the direct apply instead of being transferred by the company.

From time to time I see from the great resignation in US to the rise of vacancies in the US for non-farming job, but why the government still makes it so difficult to get a visa for foreigners to work in the US, despite there're apparently not enough suitable labor for the job market?

Comment: If anywhere, this should be posted on Politics not The Workplace.

Comment: Are many foreign workers interested in working part-time minimum wage for a restaurant?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek In the UK anyway - yes. The service industry ran on central European staff for a good few years, until Brexit anyway. And customer service improved because it was from a bunch of workers who wanted to do the job.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on Politics SE. BTW, why am I only allowed to vote to move it to Meta? It does not belong there.

Comment: See [politics.se]

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane To prevent [migrating crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446) and pushing low-quality questions to other sites, creating work for the community and moderators elsewhere. The moderators here can migrate a question to any site if they think it is truly a good question which would be well received on another site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there *IS* enough suitable labor in the US for almost all positions.  What we have is a struggle over compensation.  Many firms are trying to pay 60% - 75% of what skilled labor is paid, and then claiming there is a worker shortage when they can't fill positions.

Answer (score 2):

Many reasons, but the main one is that government has different priorities in terms of foreign policy than the private sector.